# Postgres Backup

Tags: postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

I was tasked to create weekly and daily snapshot backups of the data. 
Since I just started working with Postgres, I found the option to use pg_dump for the backup. 
Unfortunately the server being used does not have any room left on the /var directory where I am running the backup. After I execute it, it runs out of space and stops halfway through. The database backup ran with pg_dump dbname > file.gz is over 7gb since i tried running it inside the /tmp directory and it also crashed. As an alternative, I tried using the opt/app directory you see below, since it has the most amount of data available but i can a permission denied message. Are there any alternatives to accomplish my task? Should i look into gaining permission to the /opt/app directory or the backup should not be stored there?

[image]

Would the pg_dump name > output serve as a full weekly backup, or the daily snapshot?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must consider the database size first.
With psql:

```
postgres=# select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) from pg_database;
```

Steps:

With /opt/app, create a new directory to allocate the database backups. Verify the permissions, or you can create a directory with root user.

```
cd /opt/app/
mkdir backups
#change your directory backup group and permissions to postgres user.
chown postgres:postgres /opt/app/backups
chmod 750 /opt/app/backups
```

Now you have permissions to write files into /opt/app/backups 
Backup database with postgres user (or anywhere)

```
NOW=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
# generate a plain dump
# The -F option to create a custom backup (compressed and perform with pg_restore)
pg_dump database_name >/opt/app/backups/backup-$NOW.sql
```

Notes:
  You can generate custom dumps with -F option [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

pg_dump is full database backup not incremental.

You can cron activities daily or weekly. [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Be careful if you have roles associated in the database. In this case you can use pg_dumpall, for backup the pg_catalog.

Sorry my unreadable English... I speak spanish so close :)